# A warning and an unknown command (XeTeX)

Tags: errors, warnings

Why does `\T{foo}` yield `LaTeX Warning: Command \m invalid in math mode on input line 456.`? And what *is* `\C`, which yields `LaTeX Error: Command \C unavailable in encoding EU1.`? What is that `\m` the warning mentions?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,draft]{report}
\usepackage{fontspec,xltxtra,xunicode}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
$$\~{}\T{}$$
\C
\end{document}
```

Comment: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/34e8513ec011e2d0c993

Comment: Please place examples in the question (see my edit) not on external sites.

Comment: `\T{#1}` is defined as `\~{\m {#1}}`, giving rise to the warning containing `\m` when using `\T`.

Comment: Hmm. `\~` is a tilde accent. But what is `\m`? And what about `\C`?

Comment: Also see [Why is `\[` … `\]` preferable to `$$`?](http://goo.gl/GvmWy)

Comment: Where did you find those command documented?

Comment: With `\usepackage[T2A]{fontenc}` (not something I use), `\C{a}` typesets a double-grave accent over the 'a'; but then you shouldn't be using XeTeX....  But why are you hoping to use `\C` without any definition (or what 'default' definition were you expecting)? If you want, you can overwrite `\C` with `\def` or `\renewcommand`.

Comment: @egreg I didn't find them documented. I'm defining a set of `\+cap letter` to be replaced with the letter in `mathbb` (e.g. \newcommand{\A}{\mathbb{A}}, and I bumped on these already defined commands and a bunch of others which I found out what they did and subsequently renamed with `\let` and redefined with `\renewcommand`. Before meddling with those commands I'd like to know _what_ I'm overwriting. That also answers @jon: I don't know what default definition there is, that's _precisely_ my question!

Comment: So you say `\C` has an encoding-dependent definition. I had no idea such commands existed, nor am using fontenc in any case. The default encoding probably doesn't have a definition for it then, right? But still, what is `\m`?

Comment: Besides, `\C` must have sth to do with `hyperref`, as removing that package makes it an `Undefined control sequence` rather than a `Command not available in ...`.

Comment: No: `\usepackage{fontspec}` effectively does a `\RequirePackage[T1]{fontspec}` (thus you can load `fontspec` and `fontenc` if you need to and use `xelatex`, but you probably shouldn't in most cases).

Comment: But good point: `hyperref` loads `puenc.def`, which has `\DeclareTextCommand{\C}{PU}[1]{#1\83\017}% U+030F` for the PDF Unicode Encoding (= PU; see `encguide.pdf`), which is the [Combining double grave accent](http://unicode-table.com/en/search/?q=U%2B030F).

Comment: Uh-huh. Yet even in "`encoding EU1`" as I apparently am I can typeset that double grave by `\G`, so why do I have two apparently equivalent commands, one working (`\G`), and one with which LaTeX complains it is "`unavailable in encoding EU1`"?

Comment: Well, I suppose that is more a question for @HeikoOberdiek, but I'd (inexpertly) guess it's because `hyperref` has to worry about a lot more encodings than any single user is like to need to....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When finding out that some unknown command is already defined, the best strategy is *not* redefining them.

The command `\T{}` is equivalent to `\~{\m{}}`, where `\m` typesets the “hook above accent” (in Unicode, COMBINING HOOK ABOVE U+0309), and `\~` is the usual tilde accent.

The command `\C` is defined by `hyperref`, more precisely by `puenc.def` for printing the “double grave accent” (in Unicode, COMBINING DOUBLE GRAVE ACCENT U+030F). The PU encoding is used for printing the bookmarks, so it's not really related to TeX and friends.

Both accents are mainly for IPA linguistic matters.